# Expected value of betting gains (de Finetti)/ Law of Total Probability

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, probability-theory, expectation, bayesian

Reading de Finetti's "Foresight", there is an issue I would like to clarify:

We have $n$ mutually exclusive events, $E_1, E_2, \dots, E_n$, that we believe to occur with probability $p_1, p_2, \dots, p_n$ respectively. Now we want to bet on those events, so if for example $E_1$ materialized and the others not, we would make a gain of $(1-p_1)S_1 - p_2S_2 - \dots -p_nS : = G_1$, that is we wager $p_1S_1 + p_2S_2+ \dots + p_nS_n$ to win either $S_1, S_2$, or $S_n$.

This gives a system of linear equations, with the determinant of the coefficient matrix necessarily equal to zero. Otherwise, we could construct a Dutch Book.

$$ \begin{vmatrix}
1-p_1 & -p_2 & -p_3 &\dots & -p_n \\
-p_1 & 1-p_2 & -p_3 & \dots & p_n \\
\vdots &  \vdots & \vdots & & \vdots \\
-p_1 & -p_2 & -p_3 & \dots & 1-p_n
\end{vmatrix} = 1 - \sum_{i = 1}^n p_i = 0
$$

De Finetti now claims that, if the determinant is equal to $0$, the expected value of the gains is equal to $0$, or $\sum_{i=1}^n p_iG_i = 0$. I verified the result for the first three dimensions, but have failed to generalize it so far.

Any input would be highly appreciated!

Comment: Interesting question; I'll probably be back to it later. One thought is that if the expected value is not $0$ then a Dutch book would exist. $\qquad$

Comment: The argument goes like this: the determinant is necessarily 0, otherwise we could easily find $S_1, S_2, \dots , S_n$ such that $G_1, G_2, \dots, G_n$ are all positive. The imposed condition otherwise known as Law of Total Probability is also sufficient, de Finetti says, as the expected winnings being zero show.